# Injective module is stalkwise injective

Tags: sheaf-theory, abelian-categories, injective-module

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff locally compact topological space, $R$ be a sheaf of $\mathbb{C}_X$-algebras on $X$. If necessary, we can assume that $(X,R)$ is a complex manifold. If $M$ is an injective object of the category $\mathrm{Mod}(R)$, and $x\in X$, then is the stalk $M(x)$ an injective $R(x)$-module?

It is proved in 6.24, p.448 of "Analytic $D$-modules and applications" by Björk. But I cannot understand his proof at all.

Below, for a sheaf $F$ on $X$ and a closed embedding $j:Z\to X$, the sheaf $j_*j^{-1}F$ is denoted by $F_Z$. The collection of injective $R$-modules is denoted by $i(R)$.
[image]

Comment: I don't quite get the notation in the excerpt you posted, but note that taking stalks is right-adjoint to the exact skyscraper functor. Prove, in general, that a right-adjoint preserves injectives if its left-adjoint is exact.

Comment: Dear @Thorgott, Thank you for your comment. Your last sentence is right. Concerning your first sentence, you mean the taking stalks is LEFT-adjoint to the exact skyscraper functor, don't you?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. My comment is not helpful.